# Cancelled orders move to Trash automatically in Woocommerce - how to disable?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, order, trash

I have a Wordpress 5.4.1. website, with Woocommerce 4.1.1. installed.

It seems that orders which have the status "Cancelled" move to Trash automatically after one month passes (from the order date). 
Is there a way to disable this feature? I want all orders to stay as Cancelled, in order to keep them in the database.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  https://hitusupdesigns.com/blog/woocommerce-unpaid-order-cancelled-time-limit-reached-fix/

Answer (score 1):

A clue: backoffice > woocommerce > settings > tab account/confidentiality > at bottom "Retention of personal data" > change date for the cancelled orders